# Retrieve [String] from [object HTMLCollection]

Tags: javascript, swift, alamofire, wkwebview, htmlcollection

I've been struggling with this. I have a valid javascript command which I send from my wkwebview:

```
document.getElementById('qlist-wrapper').getElementsByClassName('question-summary narrow').toString();
```

When I type this from the Safari console I get back

```
"[object HTMLCollection]"
```

But when I try to use the returned object, I'm at a loss. I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" (Code=1, plus an address).  there are 4 payload objects associated with the "html: Any" object; they are all 0s. Here's the code in context:

```
webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('qlist-

wrapper').getElementsByClassName('question-summary narrow').toString();", completionHandler: { (html: Any, error: Error?) in
        print("\(html)")
        if let error = error {
            print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

Ultimately my goal is to turn the html collection into an array of Swift strings. How do I do that? I would very much welcome a JSON solution (perhaps using Alamofire), but I simplified my approach to first get something working. (I've worked with Alamofire in the past, but not so much JSON). 
If I try to look at the variable before printing it, i get:

```
po html
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xfffffffffffffff8).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

Comment: It sounds like you are getting back an array, right? What line causes the crash?

Comment: No. I'm getting back a bad pointer. the print("\\(html)") causes the exception in this case, but even in the debugger I can't print any values associated with the variable. (I'll add this to the question)

Comment: I'm assuming you've checked that `error` is `nil`?

Comment: Yes. If I move the error check before the print statement, I also get EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. (the error isn't nil, but also isn't usable as an error)

Comment: Perhaps you should fix your JavaScript first. Even if the evaluation returned successfully, you can't do much with the **string** `"[object HTMLCollection]"` (you should not call `.toString()` on the collection).

Comment: "[object HTMLCollection]" is what shows in the Safari javascript console,  not what I get in swift. (If I click on the down arrow, I see the correct array). I don't know JavaScript well enough to know what to ask for / swift expects to receive. If I remove .toString() I get the exact same results. What is wrong with my JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really have two problems in this question:

> 1) How do I get an HtmlCollection converted into an Array? and
>
> 2) Why am I getting exceptions when I try to work with the results of
>   my javascript call from the WKWebView.

I solved the first piece of this puzzle, so I will document that here and close this. Once I have a better handle on JavaScriptCore (where I expect the ultimate solution lies), I will post a new question and cross reference that question/solution from here.

If I type the following into the Web Inspector Console in Safari, I get desired conversion from HtmlCollection to Array:

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('qlist-wrapper').getElementsByClassName('question-summary narrow'));
```